# Como filtro por dos variables en Login con JQUERY

Tags: php

Primero y antes que nada no se si es mejor hacer el login con PHP directamente, porque estoy trayendo los usuarios mediante una peticion Ajax para filtrar por el nombre de usuario y pass, y la idea es si existe, hacer otra peticion ajax para cargar la sesion.
O es mejor mandar nombre y pass al servidor.
Pero mi duda para hacer lo primero es que necesito filtrar el JSON por dos valores, tengo esto:

```js
var usuarios;
$(document).ready(function() {
    usuarios = listar();
    buscarUser($("#usuario").val());
    });
function buscaUser(user){
    var fil = usuarios.filter(function(e){
       return e.idusuario=user;
    });
}
function listar(){

    accion="listarusers";
 return $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/models/claseLogin.php",
            data: { "accion": accion}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
     
               
            }
         
  

        }  
});
};
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: lo mejor y más seguro es pasar la data al servidor y que sea este el que se encargue de buscar y validar al usuario para luego crear la sesión, pues estas dejando expuestos todos los usuarios de tu base de datos con lo que haces

Comment: Ok..muchas gracias. Lo voy a cambiar.